# when pressed wil ++ or -- a value, numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric-keypad

Using numeric keypad I have added a .switch handler which when clicked will bring the value back to '0' (test purpose only)

If the value is +32 and the button is pressed I would like it to change to -32, vice versa.

so far I have only gotten it to return to 0, i was thinking then deleting or adding the val again, even tried -- `$('#myInput').val());`

```
$('.switch').click(function () {
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
        $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) - $('#myInput').val());
    }
    if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length < 0) {
        $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) + $('#myInput').val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is switch back and forth between a positive/negative number you can make your code much simpler and lose all the `if` conditions:

```
$('.switch').click(function () {
    var $input = $('#myInput');
    $input.val() != "" && !isNaN($input.val()) && $input.val(-$input.val());
});
```

This is the equivalent of multiplying the number by `-1`, which will have the same effect.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LESUw/)

Comment: +1, but consider the target audience when replacing an `if` with `&&` with no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#myInput').val().length < 0`
when will a length of a string be less than zero?

`parseInt($('#myInput').val()) + $('#myInput').val()`
this doesn't actually do numeric addition, if th value is the string `1` then it will be like doing `1+"1"` which will return `11`

I think what you're looking for is :

```
$('.switch').click(function () {
            var val = parseInt($('#myInput').val());
            $('#myInput').val(-val);
    });
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/38esg/)